# Why did Alice give an empty gun to Doc?

Tags: plot-explanation, resident-evil, resident-evil-the-final-chapter

In ***[Resident Evil: The Final Chapter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2592614/)*** (2016), why did Alice give an empty gun to Doc?

There is a scene where Doctor Isaacs reveals that Doc is a clone and working for the Umbrella Corp., but Alice gave him the empty gun even before this scene.

Answer (score 3):

Because the Red Queen told her that there is a traitor informant that works for Umbrella among them when she gave her the earpiece after she told them about umbrella intentions to end the world, So Alice suspected him.